Regex syntax to rename a file in Max/MSP
I'm saving a file from a buffer to disk by appending the date and time to the file name.
The problem is that if I save a file that already has a date & time, the new date & time will be appended, leading to a file name with
two dates, which I want to avoid.
For example:

Input: sample_name.wav

1st write: sample_name [yyyy-mm=dd hhmmss].wav

2nd: sample_name [yyyy-mm=dd hhmmss] [yyyy-mm=dd hhmmss].wav


I need help creating a regexp expression to remove the contents of the square brackets "[...]" before the last dot ".wav" in the title.
I haven't got experience in regular expressions, so I asked ChatGPT,
but it gives a wrong syntax for Max/MSP. Has anybody already experienced using regexp in this software?

Max's regexp engine
According to
Max's documentation, the regexp
engine is PCRE (PERL compatible regular expressions),
which is one of the best one and also the one used by PHP.
Important notice about the syntax
They say that you have to double all
backslashes, so instead of \s (space chars) or \d (digits),
you'll have to write \\s and respectively \\d.
In my answer, I'll leave the single backslash to keep it
readable, and add the double-backslashed version for you.
I haven't got the software installed, so I can't test it.
Proposition 1 : get rid of the last bracket block
Here, we search for the last bracket block, with optional spaces
in front of it and by capturing the file extension to put it back
in the replacement:



What?
Value




The PCRE pattern
\s*\[[^\]]*\](\.\w+)$


Double-backslashed for Max
\\s*\\[[^\\]]*\\](\\.\\w+)$


Replacement value
$1



I don't know exactly for the replacement part, what the syntax
is in Max, so it may differ a bit. Typically, it may be \1
(or even \\1) instead of $1 in the replacement value.
Pattern details:

\s* matches spaces, 0 or several times, before the brackets.
\[ matches the opening bracket.
[^abc] is used to match any char not being "a", "b" or "c".
So we'll use [^\]]* to match all chars not being "]". This will
match the date and time.
\] matches the closing bracket.
\. to match the dot char.
\w+ to match all word chars part of the extension. + means
once or several times.
Both the dot and word chars are captured in the group with the
parenthesis (\.\w+) and will create a replacement variable
named $1.

Test it in action: https://regex101.com/r/mLZsyn/1
Proposition 2 : if you can't use references to capturing groups
If you can't put a replacement value, then you could use a positive
lookahead for the file extension and replace it by nothing:



What?
Value




The PCRE pattern
\s*\[[^\]]*\](?=\.\w+$)


Double-backslashed for Max
\\s*\\[[^\\]]*\\](?=\\.\\w+$)


Replacement value
-



Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mLZsyn/2
Proposition 3 : delete all bracket blocks
And if you need to get rid of multiple bracket parts at the end
of the file name:
(?:\s*\[[^\]]*\])+




What?
Value




The PCRE pattern
(?:\s*\[[^\]]*\])+


Double-backslashed for Max
(?:\\s*\\[[^\\]]*\\])+


Replacement value
-



(?: ) is a non-capturing group, containing the optional spaces
and the bracket block. By adding the + behind, this means that
it has to appear one or several times.
By replacing it by nothing, you get rid of all bracket blocks with
optional spaces before them.
Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mLZsyn/3
Proposition 4 : only remove bracket blocks with date and time
Here, we could imagine the file name already includes some other
bracket blocks and we only want to delete ones containing a
date and time.
Let's accept dates such as your example, 2024-08=29, but also
with dots like 2024.08.29 or just with hyphens 2024-08-29.
For the time, we can't allow the usual : separator as it's not
accepted by most file systems. It's quite common to see a time
written like 23h03'02.
The regular expression pattern with the case-insensitive flag:
\s*\[\d{4}(?:[=.-]\d{2}){2} \d{2}h?\d{2}'?\d{2}\]

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/mLZsyn/4

Patrick Janser, Thanks a lot! I appreciate your help!

@IvanBrosca: Welcome! Did it work?
